# FTP folders synchronization c / obj c

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, ftp, synchronization

I have folder (with a lot of sublfolders and files) on remote server and only FTP protocol supported.

I should have synchronized copy on my device every time when user press "SYNC" button.
Content has size more than 1gb - download every time is not good idea :)

I've trying get folders structure (recursively via LIST and CWD) and get files modification date to analyze - should I download this file or no.
Is it one correct way or I missed better solution ? For now it can take around 4 minutes only for get files structure :(

Is it possible get all folders structure with filecustom fields (like modification date)?

Im on objC (iOS) and using CFNetwork sample from SimpleFTPSample (from Apple).

update:
I've found **dir -R** command - is this command standard (like LIST) or no ?

thanks,

Comment: 4 minutes to get the files structure?  How is your internet connected over there, tin cans and a string?  Hopefully you are doing all this work on a background thread.

Comment: Yes 4 minutes. Looks like library creation new connection and run LIST command.

Answer (score 0):

I've replace library to libCURL and now it works in 1 sec... I'm shock!